# ADFS inegration

Tags: adfs, aspnetboilerplate

I am implementing ADFS authentication integrating to ABP app. and i am quite new to the technology. So i have couple questions as following:

Currently, the WS-Federation Passive endpoints is a new controller i create called "/ADFS/login"; should i change to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback since ABP is ready to ADSF? Do i need to config additional parameters or code?

And for these parameter, i should ask ADFS vendor, is that correct ?

```
<add key="ExternalAuth.WsFederation.IsEnabled" value="false" />
<add key="ExternalAuth.WsFederation.MetaDataAddress" value="" />
<add key="ExternalAuth.WsFederation.Wtrealm" value="" />
```

And i read a thread at https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4222

1. Add ADFS to AD server.
2. Change aspnetzero app to be secure(from http to https)
3. Change Startup.Configuration. add wsfederation after app.UseAbp().

Do i need to setup AD server on the web app server, since ADFS server is on AWS.

Thank you for your kindly answer.

Comment: which template are you using?

Comment: Can you refer the steps https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=9868#p9868?

Comment: I am using .net mvc + angular

Comment: As i mention i have read the thread but since i am still here in adfs, i just want to make sure the adfs overview

Comment: @viveknuna How does the `5. Change AppSettingProvider startup configuration to use https url.` is done? Can you please explain in more details?

Comment: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userName
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager 2.FindByNameAsync(String userName)` This is the error I am getting with above config and URL in browser is `Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2FApplication&tenancyName=Default`